# Pagination with id in url instead od "?page="

Tags: python, django, listview, pagination

I have an application in Django 1.8 and my problem is the parameter "?page=" in the address.
My goal is address in 127.0.0.0.1/blog/1 - and search results.
Can I count on a hint?

My urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', MyListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    url(r'/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.BlogDetailView.as_view(), name='blog_detail'),
]
```

My view:

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = models.Blog
    queryset = models.Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    template_name = 'blog/blog_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog_list'
    paginate_by = 10
```

code in template

```
{% if is_paginated %}
  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in paginator.page_range %}
      {% if page_obj.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Why are you passing all blogs in context again when you have defined queryset in your ListView?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar you are right, fixed. Any idea to solve main problem in the issue?

Comment: So you want to use id for pagination for page number instead of 'page' in querystring?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar yes, under `127.0.0.0.1/blog/1` - 10 items, under `127.0.0.0.1/blog/2` - another 10 and so on.

Comment: It would be difficult to manage the way you want it. For alternative solution, see my answer

Comment: There is no difference between `127.0.0.0.1/blog?my_page_number=2` and `127.0.0.0.1/blog?page=2`

Comment: If you override the `page_kwarg` as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to manage the way you want it. If you just have problem with page keyword for pagination, you can change argument used for pagination by setting 'page_kwarg' in ListView. like this

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    model = models.Blog
    queryset = models.Blog.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    template_name = 'blog/blog_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog_list'
    paginate_by = 10
    page_kwarg = 'my_page_number'
```

Now you can use use `127.0.0.0.1/blog?my_page_number=2` for paagination

Or if really want to pass page number as url paraameter, you have override `paginate_queryset` method in list view and do override `page_kwarg` there .

For source, see here https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L54